# import all variables from a file.js with an " import './file.js' " summoning

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with the import function, I wish use an import like for css, I mean "import './file.css'" then all the css attributes are diffused in the file. I have tried the same with ReactJS but it fails.

***My expectation is to imitate the css import for js files, but it doesn't work.***

[Here my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5k7kw92l64)

Here is the relevant code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

impoprt sample from "./sample"
    import "./exported.js";
    import "./styles.css";

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {sample[2]}
      {text1}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I'm getting the error at the line when no using the star's import:

```
  {text1}
```

I'm wondering how make something similar. Any hint would be great,

thanks

Comment: Will you copy/paste your code here in addition to the sandbox link? Also, what happens when you run your app? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: [Take a look at this fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/yv77n424q1)

Comment: Does `import * as exported from './file.js'` not get what you want?

Comment: It is picking up your CSS already.  What else are you expecting?

Comment: Please post the code, not just a link to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offending code in your sandbox is: `import "./exported.js";`

One source of confusion is that you are using Create React App, which hides away the webpack magic which allows you to import your CSS files as `import "./styles.css";`. 
This is not how module exports and imports work. I would recommend reading the section on exporting and importing details on [exploringjs.com](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_importing-exporting-details)

What you are doing is essentially an **empty import**, i.e. you are not importing anything, just executing the file.

> Empty import: only loads the module, doesn’t import anything. The
>   first such import in a program executes the body of the module.
>   import 'src/my_lib';

But here are various ways to import something in a nutshell.

Assumption: your `./exported.js` file has the following exports:

```
// some other code
export { text1, text2 };
export default config;
```

Then you can import them in various formats

```
// import only the default export
import config from './exported.js';
// This only imports the export qualified with default, it ignores others 
// i.e. 
console.log(config); //works
console.log(text1); // fails
console.log(text2); // fails

// import everything the module exports, but as a namespace
import * as myLib from './exported.js';
// usage: all named exports are properties of the myLib object
console.log(myLib.text1); // works
console.log(myLib.text2); // works
console.log(myLib.config); // should not work, unless you have also exported config as a named export

// import only what you need
  import { text1, text2 } from './exported.js';
  console.log(text1); // works
  console.log(text2); // works

// you can also rename them
  import { default as x, text1 as a, text2 as b } from './exported.js';
  console.log(x); // works --> config
  console.log(a); // works --> text1
  console.log(b); // works --> text2
```

Comment: Okay so that mean I have to create a webpack magic to make the same way that css at the end

Comment: no, I think webpack magic is overkill. Best way would be to use an appropriate import statement and sticking to the specification. This allows you to take advantage of any tooling support improvements (click to definition in your editor for example) and is an important input for tools like webpack to optimize your bundle appropriately. Do you have any concerns with using imports as mentioned in the answers?

Comment: "Do you have any concerns with using imports as mentioned in the answers" that was for optimize my code simply, your precisions are really relevant

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `import defaultExport from 'moduleName';` so you can use `defaultExport` in your code.

Doing `import 'moduleName';` will only run the code in the module but not import anything (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only) for more info)

In your sandbox, doing `import sample from 'sample.js';` would do it.

Comment: yes for the sample it's a typo of mine when writting my topic, I have edited it, okay I see better but in this case it would flow on the "text1" element, hence correctly renders it IMHO ?

Comment: [" This runs the module's global code, but doesn't actually import any values."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only) it run on the global code so'

Comment: You are exporting `text1` differently, so it requires a different method to import it.

When you have named exports and not default ones, the correct syntax to import them with is `import {export} from 'moduleName'`. 

In your example you would need to do `import {text1} from  './exported';`

@dubes gets into more detail in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code cause a breaking a import, that didn't let  include your css file, the problem is importing **export.js** and **sample.js** it must include using a correct **Destructuring**, e.g.:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { text1, text2 } from "./exported.js";
import sample from "./sample.js";
import "./styles.css";
```

Here complete sample [Code Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/9z38qrwy9w).

More info about **import** statement: [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)
 **Destructuring assignment** statement: [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) .

Best regards.